Code not working on website (working fine on Codepen)
I have some code for rotating circular text on my website that was working fine until recently. Now I am getting some error messages and the text is just displaying as normal static, horizontal text. I can't figure out how the code can be working fine in Codepen but on the website it is not working. What is also weird is that in the Elementor editor on the website, the circular rotating text is working fine but on the live site it's broken?!



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .contact-text")
const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(40)
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  text.style.transform = `rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`
  });

  });
.circle-text { 
overflow: hidden; 
    
}

.circle-text text { 
    font-family: "Alliance No 2", Sans-serif; 
    font-size: 17.2px; 
    font-weight: 500; 
    
}

.circle-text svg { 
    position: relative;
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 220px;

  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
     -moz-animation-name: rotate;
      -ms-animation-name: rotate;
       -o-animation-name: rotate;
          animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
      -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
       -o-animation-duration: 5s;
          animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
      -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
       -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(0); }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotate {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(0); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
    from { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    to { -o-transform: rotate(0); }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(0); }
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-text">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <path id="circlePath" d="M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "/>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="75" fill="none"/>
    <g>
        <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none"/>
        <text fill="#FB4D98">
            <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">ROTATE . ROTATE . ROTATE . ROTATE . </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>




I have just added the library to the code in my question but the issue remains as you can see. You can visit the Codepen example linked in my question also.

You are looking for an element with class contact-text which is a descendant of an element with class circular-text, but I can't see any elements with either of those classes in the HTML you have provided. Where are they created, or are they circle-text and circlePath?

What is CircleType supposed to do? It gives error since it is not a text you are bending but an SVG
Just remove it - you do not even need jQuery, it is the CSS that rotates the text
Also you cannot scroll something that is overflow: hidden


.circle-text {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-text text {
  font-family: "Alliance No 2", Sans-serif;
  font-size: 17.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.circle-text svg {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -ms-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
<div class="circle-text">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <path id="circlePath" d="M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "/>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="75" fill="none"/>
    <g>
        <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none"/>
        <text fill="#FB4D98">
            <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">ROTATE . ROTATE . ROTATE . ROTATE . </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>



